# JQuery selected option for Dropdown is not working properly

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropdown

I have a dropdown with two options `public` and `private`. I am fetching data from database using ajax and showing in the form fields. So I have written script in JQuery to set the value to be selected. But it working properly only twice, like only once for `public` and first time for `private`.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<select name="insurance" class="form-select" id="insurance" required>
   <option value="">--Select--</option>
   <?php $insurance = App::make("App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentsController")->getInsurance(); ?>
    @foreach($insurance as $ins)  
       <option value="{{ $ins->id }}">{{ $ins->insurance }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
if(data['insurance'] != ''){  
   console.log(data['insurance']);     // showing correct value
   $('#insurance > option[value="'+data["insurance"]+'"]').attr('selected',true);
}
```

Here `data['insurance']` is my result array value from ajax.

1. First I fetch data with insurance `private` - working fine
2. Then fetch row with insurance `public`  - working fine
3. Again fetch data with `private` - not working (showing the last status only)

If try to fetch records with any value - not working.

Only first two times, it is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also remove the attribute selected of the other option via jquery.

As I see in the first occasion  gets selected,
then  since both of the are selected the first one will stay selected in the form.

Try something like this:

```
if(data['insurance'] != ''){  

   if(data['insurance'] == 'public'){
     $('#insurance > option[value="private"]').removeAttr('selected');
     $('#insurance > option[value="public"]').attr('selected', true);
   }
   else{
     $('#insurance > option[value="public"]').removeAttr('selected');
     $('#insurance > option[value="private"]').attr('selected', true);
   }

}
```

Comment: as you said, the problem is the selection is not removing on next call. but this `private` and `public` values are coming from another database table. so I cannot use directly in the condition because it may changed in the future. So I made some changes to my code and now its worked. Check my answer

Comment: I am glad you worked out :)

Comment: @geeth maybe you can accept the answer to mark as solved issue

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue adding a single line code. The actual problem is, the selected option is remains as selected always. If I select one option and then the second both will be marked as selected. So On the next calls the first option will be showing because both are selected. So I have added code to remove the selection before assign the selection to new option.

Here is my corrected code:

```
if(data['insurance'] != ''){  console.log(data['insurance']);
   $('#insurance').find('option:selected').attr('selected', false);
   $('#insurance > option[value="'+data["insurance"]+'"]').attr('selected',true);
}
```